# HTML/CSS - Stop href effecting button

Tags: html, css

I've looked at other threads however it doesn't relate to my situation in a way. A snippet of my code is:

```
<div class="rowwrap"><a href="example.com">
<button onclick='transferStock(<?php echo $UniqueID; ?>)' type='button' class='ui-disabled btn btn-primary xs'>Transfer</button></div>
```

The rowwrap div puts a href on all of the rows below however is their any way I could disable the link effecting the button so the JS will run transferStock(ID)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot have a `<button>` inside a `<a>` element.

Comment: Im not that good in php, but that echo doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @K. Daniek alone it doesn't however their is code above it which pulls from a database ;-)

Comment: @PaulBrennan Check my answer.

Comment: @K.Daniek  You are right. Thanks

Comment: @K.Daniek The `echo` really makes sense, in the way, that gives the ID from the server side to the client side. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah but I just don't know the sense to use it as a function's argument. The `transferStock(<?php echo $UniqueID; ?>)` would make sense for me if it would be without `echo`. Or I'm wrong mate?

Comment: @K.Daniek Ha ha... Yea, you are wrong mate. `:)` It is for echoing something as the **function argument**... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you for teaching me smth ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a `<button>` inside a `<a>` element. If you want to disable the button, you need to use the `disabled` attribute.

```
<button onclick='transferStock(<?php echo $UniqueID; ?>)' type='button'
        class='ui-disabled btn btn-primary xs' disabled='disabled'>Transfer</button>
```

Not just the class `disabled`, which you have already added. Also get rid of the orphaned `<a>` tag. This should work.

The removal of `<a>` tag is completely based on the PHP logic, or whichever puts it. It is better to either remove it, or use `display: none` to hide it and bring the `button` outside the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Didn't he just forgot to close the `a` tag?

Comment: @K.Daniek Yes, he did. I have also mentioned it, see: `[...] Also get rid of the orphaned <a> tag. [...]`

Comment: The <a> is still needed, just a code snippet was above. However this answer helped towards the solution.

Comment: @PaulBrennan You are welcome buddy. Glad that I was able to help you solve it. Merry Christmas mate.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `href` value with this:`#/`

> ```
> <a href="#/">Link</a>
> ```

This Snippet is to change all anchors under `.rowwrap`. Details are commented in the source:

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Collect all anchors that are descendants of .rowwrap
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.rowwrap a');

// Store the total number of anchors in qty
var qty = anchors.length;

// On each iteration, set each anchor's href value to: #/
for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
  anchors[i].href = '#/';
}
```

```html
<div class="rowwrap">
  <a href="example.com">
<button onclick='transferStock(<?php echo $UniqueID; ?>)' type='button' class='ui-disabled btn btn-primary xs'>
  Transfer
  </button>
  </a>
  <a href="example.com">
<button onclick='transferStock(<?php echo $UniqueID; ?>)' type='button' class='ui-disabled btn btn-primary xs'>
  Transfer
  </button>
  </a>
  <a href="example.com">
<button onclick='transferStock(<?php echo $UniqueID; ?>)' type='button' class='ui-disabled btn btn-primary xs'>
  Transfer
  </button>
  </a>
  <a href="example.com">
<button onclick='transferStock(<?php echo $UniqueID; ?>)' type='button' class='ui-disabled btn btn-primary xs'>
  Transfer
  </button>
  </a>
</div>
```